# Chinese simplified keyboard stops working randomly

Tags: keyboard, language, chinese

I use the ctrl+space hotkey to switch between english/chinese when writing documents. The chinese keyboard stops working randomly, however. I can see CH selected in the language bar, but typing in Word gives regular english letters (the pinyin popup doesn't appear). But if I switch to Google Chrome, it works. Why is this happening and how can this be fixed? So far I've only found that restarting the PC works, but restarting it every 20 minutes is hugely impractical.

[edit]

I noticed the pinyin dialog stops appearing after I accidentally click some combination of enter/ctrl and backspace (I believe). How do I reverse this?